# Accessing Specific Properties Inside IEnumerable

Tags: c#, xml, linq, ienumerable

I am attempting to query an XML document and return a count stored in a COUNT tag inside of a METEDATA tag. The thing is that I am having difficulty in accessing the property strCount for use in the program. Ive considered looping through the IEnumerable but was hoping to be able to access he value in a cleaner manner. Such as return countQ.strCount our countQ["strCount"]. I knw those do not work in this instance but wanted to illustrate the desire to use the name of the property I want the value as opposed to indexing or a loop.

**CODE**

```
Private XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);    

public class entityCount
{
    public string strCount { get; set; }
}


public IEnumerable<entityCount> queryCount(){
        var countQ = this.doc.Descendants("METADATA") .Select(m => new entityCount {
            strCount = m.Element("COUNT").Value
        });

        return countQ.....?;    
}
```

**ABBREVIATED XML**

```
<PRODUCTION_SET>
    <METADATA>
        <COUNT>322</COUNT>
    </METADATA>
    <ENTITY>
        <METADATA>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <foo>x</foo>
            <bar>y</bar>
        </METADATA>
    </ENTITY>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <ENTITY>
        <METADATA>
            <ID>322</ID>
            <foo>x</foo>
            <bar>y</bar>
        </METADATA>
    </ENTITY>
</PRODUCTION_SET>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the count in the first metadata tag, you could just do this: `countQ.First()`

If what you're interested is only the metadata tag directly in PRODUCTION_SET, you should probably not use Descendants (which would go looking for it deeper, even in individual entities, ignoring the context), but instead find the PRODUCTION_SET tag and then do `.Elements().Select(...).Single()`. Single() is almost the same as First(), but it will make sure there is only one element you're looking for. In that case, the code would look like this:

```
public entityCount queryCount(){
    return this.doc.Root.Elements("METADATA").Select(m => new entityCount {
        strCount = m.Element("COUNT").Value
    }).Single();
}
```

Comment: This is returning a type error.
"Cannot Implicity;y concert type namespace.enitiyCount to System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerabl<namespace.entityCount>

Missing a Cast?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I changed it to return entityCount instead of IEnumerable. Is that what you're looking for? Then you can use it in this way: `queryCount().strCount`

Comment: Oh just saw that! I like how clean this is!

Comment: After reading you're question again, it seems like you want to return the strCount property directly. If that's the case, then of course you could chage the return value to string and and change Single() to Single().strCount. But now you don't need the entityCount class at all and could just select the value directly:

Comment: `Select(m => m.Element("COUNT").Value).Single()`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the the IEnumerable<T> to a list and access the elements via their indices:

```
int cnt = countQ.ToList()[0].strCount;
return cnt;
```

The question is, does your query only ever return one item?  If you know that you only have one item, you can just use `First()`:

```
int cnt = countQ.First().strCount;
return cnt;
```

Comment: we cannot index IEnumerable object

Comment: in this particular example it will only ever be one item. I will have a separate query that will infact return multiple.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the first item of the [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) using [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like:

```
var queryCountResult = countQ.FirstOrDefault();
if(queryCountResult !=null)
{
   var count = queryCountResult.strCount;
}
```